# Using aggregation thresholds in a Cypher query to refine results

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm trying to write a Cypher query that uses aggregation to pull back the most relevant paths.  My  desired path is described in the MATCH clause below

```
MATCH p=(a:TYP1)--(b:TYP2)--(c:TYP3)--(d:TYP4)
RETURN a, count(distinct d) as cntTYP4
ORDER BY cntTYP4 DESC
```

This produces a list of nodes of TYP1 sorted in descending order by the number of TYP4 nodes that they link to in the MATCH clause.  What I would like to do is return all paths p where cntTYP4 > 5 (for example).  My attempts to structure a query this far have been unsuccessful.  Hopefully I'm missing something obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WITH` to do this. Something like:

```
MATCH p=(a:TYP1)--(b:TYP2)--(c:TYP3)--(d:TYP4)
WITH a, count(distinct d) as cntTYP4 
WHERE cntTYP4 > 5
RETURN a, cntTYP4
ORDER BY cntTYP4 DESC
```

HTH,

Andrés